# How to navigate through a list by foreign key in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql, .net, linq-to-sql

I have these four tables `SI_FILTROSRELATORIO_[something]` in which one column is `ID_FILTROSRELATORIO` which is a foreign key to a `SI_FILTROSRELATORIO` table. I wanted to do something like:

```
var myList = db.SI_FILTROSRELATORIOs
               .Single([some query])
               .SI_FILTROSRELATORIO_[something]s
```

I know this is possible because I have another 2 tables which I can do this. I'm trying to replicate the effect but I don't know if I'm missing some detail because the `SI_FILTROSRELATORIO_[something]`'s property doesn't show up in a `SI_FILTROSRELATORIO`'s entry, and I can't figure why.

The relationship is actually like this:

[image: Field on SI_FILTROSRELATORIO]
[image: Field on SI_FILTROSRELATORIO_[something]]
[image: Foreign Key relationship]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SI_FILTROSRELATORIO_[something] had no Primary Key column. The direction of the relationship also was inverted.